# Reset binding is blocking UI in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Im my application user can add DataGrids and visualize some data that is being fetched from the server. Problem is, that every 500ms data is fetched and I need to refresh bindings on DataGrid. I am binding to BindingList (with observable collection I have the same problem) and this binding refresh is blocking my UI thread.

Since DataGrids were created on UI thread I am using Dispatcher to update bindings on them:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
  TableConfiguration.ObservedRegisters.ResetBindings();
});
```

Is there any way to make this process faster? I looked on the performance profiler tool and according to it, the line above is causing all the fuss. When I comment it out UI works smoothly, but datagrids values are not refreshing of course.

ItemSource of DataGrid is Binding list and it can have over 50 elements. With three of those grids I can't do anything on the UI.
I know - I should maybe use ObservableCollection, but nevertheless, problem is still the same. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every 500ms is ever half second.
I would consider throttling it back to every second or maybe more.
If they need to see changes more frequently then a datagrid will be making the job of reading the data harder than some graphical representation.

In WPF it's usual to use observablecollection rather than bindinglist. Wouldn't bindinglist notify change on every row and every property when you resetbindings?

I would change to observablecollection and use inotifypropertychange to notify changes to the collection or properties.

Only change and notify change on what you need to.

If everything must change.
Rebuild the collection and set the property the itemssource is bound to, raise propertychanged on that.

If the way the data works is that one or two records will change rather than everything then instead you could set those specific items in the observablecollection to a new instance.

This seems an unlikely scenario. All your data changing every half second.
Much more likely is one or two properties, maybe a row changes.

If just one or two properties change then instead change just those properties and use change notification on them.

If everything is very very dynamic and you need a datagrid then you could use a dependency object as a viewmodel. Use dependency objects for each row with dependency properties for each property/column.  Bindings resolve quicker on dp. But again. Use an observablecollection.

There's also the cost of measure arrange on all the cells. If you can work with fixed width columns that would be reduced.

Comment: thank you for your reply. yes, my data could be very dynamic and it has to be done in a table form. Throttling it to 1sec or more won't help i think, UI will still get blocked.  I will try to experiment with ObservableCollection, maybe it will speed things up a little bit. You are really saying, that only way to improve performance is to use DP on each row instead of  ItemSource? This sucks, 200-300 rows are not that many really, I didn't suspect it will be such an isue

Comment: What you're doing, I think, is the equivalent of raising property changed on every property and collection changed on every row. If you have auto sized columns then the whole thing is then laid out and measure arrange called on everything bound - which can be quite costly itself.

Comment: I don't have autosized columns. I am binding my DataGrid to List<Register>. Register is a class, that stores data from the device (it has name, value and unit, that are shown in rows). And only value changes, name and unit stays the same.

Comment: If you retain exactly the same rows then I'd try an observablecollection<t> where t implements inotifypropertychanged raising property changed on change of property. Take your new data and match new with old records and set value if different. Then you're only getting change notification of one property per record and only when that has changed.